# How to find the average value of $f(x,y)$ on $R=\{(x,y): -1\le x\le1,0\le y\le3\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Given $R=\{(x,y): -1\le x\le1,0\le y\le3\}$

For the function $f(x,y)$ evaluate $\int\int_R f(x,y)dA$ and find the average value of $f(x,y$ on $R$

$f(x,y)=x^3+xy^3-3y$

**My Try:**

$=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^3x^3+xy^3-3ydydx$

$=\int_{-1}^{1}(x^3y+\dfrac{xy^4}{4}-\dfrac{3y^2}{2})\bigg|_0^3dx$

$=\int_{-1}^{1}3x^3+\dfrac{81x}{4}-\dfrac{27}{2}dx$

$=\dfrac{3x^4}{4}+\dfrac{81x^2}{8}-\dfrac{27x}{2}\bigg|_{-1}^{1}$

$=-\dfrac{54}{2}$

$=-27$

Is my above answer correct?

How to find the average value of $f(x,y)$ on $R$?

Comment: Check your work by integrating by x first.  To find the average divide the result by the area.

Comment: I was composing a comment to your fib gcd question but you deleted it before I could reply.

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry for that. I opened it now. Can you please provide your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, not quite!

First, we need to know how exactly the average value of a two variable function $f(x,y)$ is computed. Typically, the following equation is utilized to compute the average value of a function $f(x,y)$ over a rectangle $R$:

$$f_{ave} = \frac{1}{\text{Area}(R)} \iint_R f(x,y) dxdy$$

Since we're given a rectangle $R$ with side lengths $2$ and $3$, we find that $\text{Area(R)}$ = 6.

So, our equation above becomes:

$$f_{ave} = \frac{1}{6} \iint_R f(x,y) dxdy$$

Then, we need only simply compute $\iint_R f(x,y) dxdy$ which you have done correctly:

$$\iint_R f(x,y) dxdy = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{3} (x^3 + 3xy^3 -3y)dydx = -27$$

So, your answer will simply be:

$f_{ave} = \frac{1}{6} (-27) = -\frac{27}{6}$

Comment: Can the area be in negative?

Comment: No, the area of the rectangle itself should not be negative. The side lengths should all be positive so we take the absolute value of the following differences: 1-(-1) = 2 and 3-0 = 3. This is how we get the side lengths for our rectangle, and we simply multiply the two lengths to obtain our area.